# Http post data login not working?

Tags: java, android, http, authentication, http-post

I have one problem, I want to login a website through an android device. I have looked at many samples about this, but it not working for me. This is my code :

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/login.php");
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","text/html");
    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList();
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "test1"));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pass1"));
    try {
        UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs, HTTP.UTF_8);

        /** Assign the POST data to the entity */
        httppost.setEntity(p_entity);

        /** Perform the actual HTTP POST */
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        txtView.setText(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        uee.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't understand new BasicNameValuePair("username", "test1") . What is attibute here .???

```
<input type="text" name="username" size="25" maxlength="40" value="" class="post" id="autofocus" tabindex="1"/>

<input type="password" name="password" size="25" maxlength="32" class="post" tabindex="2"/>
```

It just return login page . It not pass parameters to login . Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

`test1` is your username and `pass1` is your password.

if you are getting username and password from edittexts then use this code

```
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", ed_user.getText().toString()));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", ed_pass.getText().toString()));
```

where `ed_user` and `ed_pass` are your edittexts

Comment: Yeah , but it not working for me . I try many times . But it just return login page . I want after i login . It redirect to home page . But It always return login.php :-?

Comment: if you are getting correct result then you need to move to next page using [intent](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/)

Comment: No , I mean that . It just return login page . It not pass data to login . I don't know why and what is happen ???

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code of the HTML page and find the following section (example):

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="/cgi-bin/websms/index.pl" onSubmit="return validate()">
```

Now update your URL in ur program according to the action="..." section of the form.